# Dry plant is back to life

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, plant-care, watering, pruning

My plant went dry when the covid started, I couldn’t give it too much attention (but it has a drip irrigation) on how it went, but then I noticed it was all dry (not a single leaf).
Some weeks ago, some leaves started to appear on two parts of the plant.

It doesn’t look like more will appear (but I don’t know).
Is there something I should do? Like trimming the dry branches? Or should I continue watering as usual (or more?).

[image: my plant]

Comment: Good question and illustration; if could include region, overall heights of the parts with leaves, branch diameters of the parts with leaves, current watering amount & frequency, and current nutrient amount & frequency, could also be helpful. We encourage you to take the [Tour], and browse through the [Help], to learn more about how the site works! Thank you! Welcome to the site!